# Unity3D and new Firebase setting (due to the Firebase 2016/05/18 update)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, setting

Google updated Firebase recently (2016/05/18) so that we need apiKey for Web or adding rules to build.gradle for Android.

I'm using Firebase in my Unity3D project and it's working now anyway with old settings.

1) Until when can I use these old settings? In fact, there is almost no setting for the apiKey or something. If I publish one working app, is it OK forever?

2) For the Unity3D, I'm using this (https://github.com/firebase/Firebase-Unity) code and my final app form is Android apk. Then, which settings do I need to apply? Android or Web? I heard that the plugin uses Web api for the Unity but it's not clear to me.

3) Above all, I need settings for my Android app. Does anybody knows how to apply new settings with Unity-Firebase application?